# Receiver Threading Profile HTTP configuration in Mule

Tags: http, mule

I've made a simple flow just to test the http:connector thing.

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="100" maxBufferSize="1000"/>
</http:connector>
```

And if i add the maxBufferSize, the flow won't work. If i remove it, the flow works in terms of when i want to call HTTP get from the browser, it keeps loading and loading.

Wanted to know why this is happening. What's the default maxBufferSize?? in the documentation isn't included. None of those values.

How can i configure this receiver propertly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this configuration in place nothing will be processed until the buffer is not filled.

If this is not what you want you should set the maxThreadsIdle at the same value.

Behind the scenes Mule uses the ThreadPoolExecutor, so read the [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for more informations

Comment: im trying different configurations but still not knowing how much to increase each of those properties... what are the convenient values.

Comment: That depends on your requirements. Can you clarify what you mean by "still not working"

Comment: yes, i get it now, depends on how many http requests i need to process at a determined amount of time. Im doing load testing... and changing the values and i could see the difference now. Thanks genjosanzo.